# Actualizar fecha por columna

Tags: sql, postgresql

cree una columna cuya fecha se va actualizando conforme se va haciendo el cambio en el valor de algun organo de la columna test name de esta tabla final
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando en el estudio no se llego a contestar el formulario del test name y solo se contesto en el formuario que no se realizo la prueba de physical examination(physical examination performed) la fecha de last date aparece nula, he probado con varias formas pero ya sea que me cambie todos los valores de last date por la misma fecha o continue dejandome fechas vacias, necesito que estos espacios vacios se llenen con la fecha de physical examination performed

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT( Max(fe.cr) ) AS "Last Date",
               sid.siteid     AS "Site ID",
               sbj.subjid     AS "Subject ID",
               vis.name       AS "Visit Name",
               perf.val       AS "Physical examination performed?",
               reas.val       AS "Reason if not done",
               DATE.val       AS "Date",
               TIME.val       AS "Time",
               CASE
                 WHEN test.name = 'Other' THEN other.val
                 ELSE test.name
               END            AS "Test name",
               res.val        AS "Result",
               clinsig.val    AS "Clinically significant?"
--siteid 
FROM   (SELECT dtc.unit_id,
               ac.affix     AS siteid,
               ac.system_id AS sitesys
        FROM   adm_centers ac
               join dat_treatment_centers dtc
                 ON ac.system_id = dtc.center_id) sid
       --Performed?
       left join (SELECT di.event_id,
                         di.system_id,
                         di.unit_id,
                         di.form_id,
                         di.val,
                         di.item_group_id
                  FROM   dat_items di
                         left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                ON di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                  WHERE  sd.item_oid = 'i_physexam_perf'
                         AND di.is_current = TRUE) perf
              ON sid.unit_id = perf.unit_id
                 AND vis.system_id = perf.event_id
       --LAST DATE
       left join (SELECT di.event_id,
                         di.system_id,
                         di.unit_id,
                         di.form_id,
                         di.val        AS sign,
                         di.created_on AS cr,
                         di.item_group_id
                  FROM   dat_items di
                         left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                ON di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                  WHERE  sd.form_oid = 'f_physexam_com'
                         AND sd.item_oid = 'i_pe_res'
                         AND di.is_current = TRUE) fe
              ON test.item_group_id = fe.item_group_id
       --Test name
       left join (SELECT di.event_id,
                         di.system_id,
                         di.unit_id,
                         di.form_id,
                         di.item_group_id,
                         di.val,
                         sig.name
                  FROM   dat_items di
                         left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                ON di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                         left join dat_igroups dig
                                ON dig.system_id = di.item_group_id
                         left join sdf_igroups sig
                                ON dig.def_id = sig.system_id
                  WHERE  sd.item_group_oid LIKE 'g_pe_%'
                         AND sd.item_oid LIKE 'i_pe_res'
                         AND di.is_current = TRUE) test
              ON sid.unit_id = test.unit_id
                 AND TIME.form_id = test.form_id
```

Si lo pongo asi se actualiza para cada organo pero me sale vacio como la segunda imagen pero si lo pongo asi

```sql
--LAST DATE
LEFT join
(
          select    di.event_id,
                    di.system_id,
                    di.unit_id,
                    di.form_id,
                    di.val        as sign,
                    di.created_on as cr,
                    di.item_group_id
          from      dat_items di
          left join sdf_datapoints sd
          on        di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
          where     sd.form_oid = 'f_physexam_com'
          and       sd.item_oid in ('i_physexam_perf',
                                    'i_pe_res')
          and       di.is_current=true) fe on test.item_group_id = fe.item_group_id
or
perf.item_group_id = fe.item_group_id
```

Me pone todo con la misma fecha

Comment: Encontre una nueva forma de solucionarlo con select
distinct(max(case when fe.cr is null then perf.cr1 else fe.cr end)) as "Last Date",  haciendo cr1 como la fecha de performed physical examination pero aun con el distinct me esta sacando fechas repetidas, de 139 valoresme esta dando 157 , como podria modificar este para que de verdad no me de valores repetidos

Comment: ok jaja termine haciendo del query principa un subquery metiendo last date dentro de distinct

Comment: ¿ya lo solucionaste? de ser así publica tu respuesta para que la comunidad sepa que la pregunta ha solido resuelta con éxito.

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(Max("Last Date")) AS "Last Date" ,
                "Site ID",
                "Subject ID",
                "Visit Name",
                "Physical examination performed?",
                "Reason if not done",
                "Date",
                "Time",
                "Test name",
                "Result",
                "Clinically significant?"
FROM            (
                                SELECT DISTINCT(Max(
                                                CASE
                                                                WHEN fe.cr IS NULL THEN perf.cr1
                                                                ELSE fe.cr
                                                END))      AS "Last Date",
                                                sid.siteid AS "Site ID" ,
                                                sbj.subjid AS "Subject ID" ,
                                                vis.name   AS "Visit Name" ,
                                                perf.val   AS "Physical examination performed?" ,
                                                reas.val   AS "Reason if not done" ,
                                                DATE.val   AS "Date" ,
                                                TIME.val   AS "Time" ,
                                                CASE
                                                                WHEN test.name = 'Other' THEN other.val
                                                                ELSE test.name
                                                END         AS "Test name" ,
                                                res.val     AS "Result" ,
                                                clinsig.val AS "Clinically significant?"
                                                --Performed?
                                left join
                                                (
                                                          SELECT    di.event_id,
                                                                    di.system_id,
                                                                    di.unit_id,
                                                                    di.form_id,
                                                                    di.val,
                                                                    di.item_group_id,
                                                                    di.created_on AS cr1
                                                          FROM      dat_items di
                                                          left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                                          ON        di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                                                          WHERE     sd.item_oid = 'i_physexam_perf'
                                                          AND       di.is_current=TRUE) perf
                                ON              sid.unit_id = perf.unit_id
                                AND             vis.system_id = perf.event_id
                                left join
                                                (
                                                          SELECT    di.event_id,
                                                                    di.system_id,
                                                                    di.unit_id,
                                                                    di.form_id,
                                                                    di.val        AS sign,
                                                                    di.created_on AS cr,
                                                                    di.item_group_id
                                                          FROM      dat_items di
                                                          left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                                          ON        di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                                                          WHERE     sd.form_oid = 'f_physexam_com'
                                                          AND       di.is_current=TRUE) fe
                                ON              test.item_group_id = fe.item_group_id
                                                --Test name
                                left join
                                                (
                                                          SELECT    di.event_id,
                                                                    di.system_id,
                                                                    di.unit_id,
                                                                    di.form_id,
                                                                    di.item_group_id,
                                                                    di.val,
                                                                    sig.name
                                                          FROM      dat_items di
                                                          left join sdf_datapoints sd
                                                          ON        di.datapoint_id = sd.system_id
                                                          left join dat_igroups dig
                                                          ON        dig.system_id = di.item_group_id
                                                          left join sdf_igroups sig
                                                          ON        dig.def_id = sig.system_id
                                                          WHERE     sd.item_group_oid LIKE 'g_pe_%'
                                                          AND       sd.item_oid LIKE 'i_pe_res'
                                                          AND       di.is_current=TRUE) test
                                ON              sid.unit_id = test.unit_id
                                AND             TIME.form_id = test.form_id
                                WHERE           perf.val IS NOT NULL
                                GROUP BY        fe.cr,
                                                2,
                                                3,
                                                4,
                                                5,
                                                6,
                                                7,
                                                8,
                                                9,
                                                10,
                                                11
                                ORDER BY        2,
                                                3)q1
GROUP BY        2,
                3,
                4,
                5,
                6,
                7,
                8,
                9,
                10,
                11
ORDER BY        2,
                3
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe brevemente cómo funciona la consulta. Lee [answer]. Recuerda que la respuesta también debe ser útil para los demás usuarios que más adelante llegaran a tener un problema similar. Luego, [acepta](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.